# LinqPad cross-database with custom DataContext

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linqpad

I'm trying to write a cross-database query to compare query results on different environments to ensure both environments are behaving the same. I want to run the same query on multiple tables to compare the results.

I'm trying to do this in a generic way so I can just provide the table I want and don't have to duplicate comparison and retreival code, but I don't know how to access the linked database with a custom `DataContext` type.

I have this `CompareResult` type that I'm using to store the differences:

```
class CompareResult<T> : CompareResult 
    where T: class
{
    public CompareResult(DataContext ctx, DataContext qaCtx, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr) {
        DevResults = ctx.GetTable<T>().Where(expr);
        QAResults = qaCtx.GetTable<T>().Where(expr);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is how to get the `qaCtx` parameter from the Linqpad `UserQuery`:

```
new CompareResult<TransferJob>(this, this.QAContext?, x => x.EffectiveDate == DateTime.Today).Dump();
```

When not using a custom DataContext, there would be a property of `this` that would point me to the other database, but when they're using the same DataContext type, I can't find anything like that. Here you can see in my connection that I'm connected to both databases in my query:

[image]

How can I specify that I want to run a query on the QA database when using a custom DataContext type for my LinqPad query?

Comment: Have you tried to ask this question on LinqPad forum? http://www.linqpad.net/Feedback.aspx

Comment: i will post there, thanks. I was thinking SO would have a higher chance of getting a response.